# How to add an event to Calendar.app with applescript(js)

Tags: javascript, applescript

I'd like to add new schedule to Calender app on iMac with applescript(javascript).

I wrote like below. But I still can't get how it works.

```
var app = Application("カレンダー")
app.activate()

var today1 = new Date()

var event = app.Event({
    description: "test",
    startDate: today1,
    alldayEvent: true
})
```

the inside of event is like this

```
app.Event({"description":"test", "startDate":Wed Dec 28 2022 17:03:03 GMT+0900 (JST), "alldayEvent":true, "make":[function anonymous]})
```

So does this mean that I could made event object?

From this on, I can't add event to the calender.

Is there any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Which is it: applescript or javascript?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941675/how-to-add-an-event-to-calendar-app-with-applescriptjs#comment132248955_74941675) @ScottHunter macOS's [Script Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript_Editor) (historically named _AppleScript Editor_) supports JavaScript. The question is about the JavaScript language.

Comment: So it is javascript; what editor you are using is irrelevant.